# Makefile: use a target from a project.mk file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile in the workspace folder. There are individual projects where there are project.mk files.

In the main Makefile, I want to use targets from the individual project.mk files.

```
all: buildUIProject1 buildUIProject2
```

Where buildUIProject1 is a target in project.mk

```
buildUIProject1: $(shell find src -name *)
  npm run build
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: thank you. I have sub directories in src.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, just a remark: prefer `find src -type f` over `find src -name *`. The former lists all files (not directories) under `src`. The latter is wrong because the `*` pattern is expanded by the shell before `find` runs, and if it expands as more than one word you will get a syntax error. And note that if you do not have sub-directories in `src`, `$(wildcard src/*)` is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd do is a recipe for the `buildUIProject1` that runs make (recursively) on project.mk. In the main makefile:

```
buildUIProject1:
    $(MAKE) -C project1/folder -f project.mk $@
```